# Compass/SASS syntax error with @include font-face();

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to convert this CSS into SASS with Compass's font-face() mixin:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'PT Sans';
  src: url('../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.eot#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
  url('../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.eot#iefix') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
  url('../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
  url('../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

This is what I've gotten:

```
@import "../compass/css3";
@include font-face("PT Sans", font-files('../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.eot', '../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.eot#iefix', '../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.ttf', '../fonts/PTSans/PTS55F_W.svg#svgFontName'));
```

But I get this syntax error:

```
Syntax error: Invalid CSS after " ": expected "{", was "@include font-f..."
```

I assume it's a stupid simple syntax error I'm missing, but I can't see it for the life of me.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted does compile correct when saved as .scss with compass used.
You might have to change to change the first line to

> @import "compass/css3";

Here is a working example with your code:
http://codepen.io/MariusRumpf/pen/oHDLh

Comment: Well I think I've set up my workflow incorrectly. I couldn't get Compass to work properly, so I downloaded the directories I needed (/compass/css3) and put it a directory above where I'm callling it. It seems to work for my other files where I call @include border-radius() and others, but not for font-face().

Comment: This is not needed if you installed compass correctly. You may find an installation tutorial for that at the compass website: [Compass Website](http://compass-style.org/install/). It should be as simple as installing ruby (Mac has it pre installed, Windows is easiest with [Rubygem Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/)) and then just typing `gem update --system` and `gem install compass` next. Then   browse to the project folder and type `compass create <myproject>` followed by `compass compile`. Where do you get stuck?